# Kernel is non-preemptive.....How?

Tags: operating-system, stack, linux-kernel, scheduling

A process which is executing in kernel mode can not be preempted.

How is it possible?

Consider the case that a process is executing in kernel mode and taking a lot of time. Due to this the rest of processes will remain in ready queue.

For example how would the process respond to timer interrupt (if it is executing in kernel mode)? Or how would it respond to high temperature cut off interrupt.

Please if somebody could clear my doubts

Comment: Could you provide an example of such an operation in kernel mode, because processes make kernel mode transition only in limited set of operations, entire process never runs in kernel mode.

Comment: suppose a user process runs for 4 seconds and at 4 sec it call system routine and the mode shifted to kernel mode.....now in kernel mode ..that system call require 3 sec...so total is 4+3=7.let us assume that time slice is 5 sec....so would the process be preempted after 5 seconds or not.(keep in mind that at 5th sec the process is running at kernel mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, your assumptions are incorrect: the Linux kernel does provide limited kernel-mode preemption, if the config options `CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY` or `CONFIG_PREEMPT` are set.

With preemption turned on, tasks won't be preempted if they are holding locks; the kernel developers pay very close attention to how long processes hold locks, and try to reduce the amount of time that locks are held. (In part for preempt, in part because the longer locks are held, the less concurrent the system may be, if several processors are contending for the same lock. If the locks are held for short times, there is less contention and potentially higher throughput.)

Furthermore, the kernel developers try to limit the length of time a process may spend in kernel mode. After all, time spent in the kernel is time that *isn't* spent in the application, doing whatever it is the application does.

If the standard Linux kernel cannot provide you with good enough hard realtime performance handling interrupts, you can of course use a system such as [RTLinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtlinux), for which [commercial support](http://www.novell.com/products/realtime/) is available.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, interrupts are able to do just what their name implies, interrupt whatever is running at the time, be it an userspace process or a system call running in the kernel.